# What does SyntaxNet's 'eval metric' mean?

Tags: python, syntaxnet

I've been playing with SyntaxNet. After each run, a line like this is printed:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Seconds elapsed in evaluation: 20.65, eval metric: 11.48%
```

I've traced it to [line 134 of parser_eval.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/parser_eval.py#L134):

```
tf_eval_epochs, tf_eval_metrics, tf_documents = sess.run([
    parser.evaluation['epochs'],
    parser.evaluation['eval_metrics'],
    parser.evaluation['documents'],
])

num_tokens += tf_eval_metrics[0]
num_correct += tf_eval_metrics[1]
(...)
eval_metric = 100.0 * num_correct / num_tokens
(...)
logging.info('Seconds elapsed in evaluation: %.2f, '
             'eval metric: %.2f%%', time.time() - t, eval_metric)
```

It seems to be a measure of accuracy, but how is it calculated and what does it mean?

Comment: I'm also looking for info regrading this.

Comment: Where you able to figure it out? I am looking to change the number of lines processed at a time (Syntaxnet procceses 1024 at a time). I also traced it until this part. I don't understand how `sess.run` works.

Comment: @kskp Nope, didn't get any further than the digging in the question. Sess.run is a Tensorflow thing, though.